# Ruby—is nesting classes and child classes the same thing?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

What's the difference between `Nested` and `Child` in the example below? Is it just different syntax for the same thing?

```
class Parent
  class Nested
    ...
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, they are different.

Nested: 'Processor' class outside of Computer can only be accessed as Computer::Processor. Nesting provides context for the inner class (namespace). To a ruby interpreter Computer and Computer::Processor are just two separate classes.

```
 class Computer
  class Processor # To create an object for this class, this is the syntax Computer::Processor.new. The Outer class provides context
```

Child: Below is class inheritance, instance/class methods of Parent class are available to Child.  Child/Parent can be instantiated like this Child.new/Parent.new

```
class Child < Parent
```

Note that `Processor` can *only* be accessed by `Computer::Processor`, just calling `Processor` will throw an error. Similarly, calling `Child` is good, but calling `Parent::Child` will throw a warning (although it will actually run ok).

Comment: Note that a class `C` nested in a module `M` is referenced in exactly the same way: `M::C`.

Answer (score 1):

Some terminology:

- `Nested` is **nested** or **inner** in the sense that it belongs to the *namespace* introduced by class `Parent`. But note as suggested by @Jorg that it is *NOT* a nested class in the usual sense (cf., [in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)).
- `Child` is a **subclass** or **child class** of class `Parent`, as specified via **subclassing**, aka **inheritance** (is-a relationship), `Child < Parent`. Roughly, `Child` inherits methods from `Parent`.

To actually understand what happens with nested classes, you need to know how constants work in Ruby.

- See [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html) for more information.
- Fundamentally, constants live in a hierarchy  of namespaces, where a namespace is a `class` or `module` definition.
- The scope operator `::` can be used to move in the hierarchy of namespaces to select constants.
- In a (first occurrence of a) `class` definition, e.g. `class C; ...; end`, a class is created and is bound to a constant `C` which becomes the name of the class.

Comment: I think it's important to mention that unlike child classes, nested classes don't give you any shared functionality. That took me a while to understand

Comment: The problem for understanding things is that people expect to understand them in isolation or by resemblance. What kind of functionality could be imaginatively shared when using nesting and why (if you can trace back your original doubts)?

Comment: @maxpleaner: Actually, they *do*. That's pretty much the *definition* of a nested class, and it is the reason why Ruby doesn't have nested classes.

Comment: "`Nested` is a **nested** or **inner** class of class `Parent`." – No, it isn't. Ruby doesn't have nested classes. The *constant* `Nested` is namespaced inside the class referenced by the constant `Parent`. But there is absolutely no relationship whatsoever between the two *classes*.

Comment: "nested/inner" here would refer to scope of constants. But I do agree that it might be misleading. Better to update the post.

Comment: I'm sorry to be misleading. I have never done Java so I didn't realize nested meant something other than namespaced there, or elsewhere

Comment: @maxpleaner: Nested classes were introduced in [Beta](http://cs.au.dk/~beta/), and also exist in its successor [gBeta](http://cs.au.dk/~eernst/gbeta/). They are used to great effect in [Newspeak](http://newspeaklanguage.org/) and [Scala](http://scala-lang.org/). If you want to learn about nested classes, do yourself a favor and just ignore Java.